# Are the symbols "$|$" and "$:$" in the definition of a set exactly the same thing?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology, definition, math-history

When I read some math books, I often see two different symbols to represent a specific condition for a set. Some of them use "$|$" before the condition, while others use "$:$".

For example of the first case, we define the outer measure induced by $\mu$ as
\begin{align*}
\mu^*(E) = \inf \Big\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(E_i) \; \big| \; E_i \in \mathbb{R}, \; E \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i \Big\}
\end{align*}
that I find in a textbook where it uses "$|$" before the condition.

As an example of the second case, we define the Sobolev space with $D^α$ denoting a weak derivative of order |α|
\begin{align*}
W_p^k(Ω) = \{ u ∈ L_p (Ω) : D^α u ∈ L_p (Ω), \; |α| ≤ k \} 
\end{align*}
that I find in a lecture note where it uses "$:$" before the condition.

My question is quite simple: **Are the symbols "$|$" and "$:$" here totally interchangeable with exactly the same meaning?** Otherwise, do they emphasize on anything different?

If they are the same, is the existence of two different notations due to some historical reason?

Comment: Yes, they are the same thing.

Comment: I think so. Some authors also use `;`

Comment: Speaking out loud, I might read $\mid$ as *"given that"* (also in conditional probability) and $:$ as *"such that"*, meaning the same thing each time

Answer (score 2):

As mrp already stated in his comment, they do indeed mean the same thing and, in my mind, get translated to "such that".

That being said, I've developed a personal style regarding these two separators that I find helpful. I always write my set builder notation as
$$
\{ x \in X \mid \ldots \},
$$
and reserve $\colon$ to seperate quantifiers from their respective formulas. So a typical set builder notation would look something like this
$$
\{ x \in X \mid \forall y \colon \phi(x,y) \},
$$
where $\phi$ is some formula. This seems to be fairly standard in the literature and the uniform presentation seems to help with the readability of complex set builder notations. I apply a very similar style to sequences
$$
(a_i \mid i \in I \wedge \forall y \colon \phi(a_i, y) ),
$$
which I don't see very often in the literature but offers the same kind of benefits.

Answer (score 1):

They have the same meaning. Choosing one or the other is a matter of style, but you should take readability into consideration.

Using $|$ gets confusing when there are absolute values involved, as in
$$ \{ |x| | |x - 2| < 3\}$$
You need to use `\mid` to get better spacing:
$$ \{ |x| \mid |x - 2| < 3\}$$
but it is still not easy to read.

In this example, $:$ reads better: $$ \{ |x| : |x - 2| < 3\} $$

I prefer to use $:$ always because it gives better spacing and is smaller.

Comment: Regarding spacing: Use \mid and \colon respectively.

Comment: @StefanMesken, `\colon` gives the wrong spacing. I use plain `:`.

Comment: Right... I wonder whether that's the reason I stopped using it as a separator.

Comment: @StefanMesken.  Jaxov spacing is so bad it needs to be revised.  Removing spaces to save a byte or two is one of the problems.

Comment: $\bigl\{|x|\ \bigr|\ \  |x-2|<3\bigr\}$? `\bigl\{|x|\ \bigr|\ \  |x-2|<3\bigr\}` — This is a pretty extreme example anyway.

Comment: I would actually err to $\{\operatorname{abs}(x)|\operatorname{abs}(x-2) < 3\}$.